# Want to use both Request::ajax() and Request to get form data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

In Laravel 5.5 I want to use `Request::ajax()` function and for that I have to replace `use Illuminate\Http\Request` with `use Request`
 After replacing namespace ajax function is working fine, but I also want to get form parameters, when I try to use `public function ajax_form(Request $request)` and `$request->parameter`

**it gives me this error:**

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::$parameter

How can I get form parameters at same time using that ajax function?

Comment: Please show the full class method

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Which class are you talking about? Controller Class?

Comment: what do you mean by *form parameter*?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to replace it, `Illuminate\Http\Request` also has the `ajax` method, but it's not static.

Injecting request object

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response()->json(['result' => true]);
    }

    return view('dashboard');
}
```

Without injecting request object

```
public function index()
{
    if (request()->ajax()) {
        return response()->json(['result' => true]);
    }

    return view('dashboard');
}
```

Comment: already tried using same, ajax request is not getting recognised with this!

Comment: How are you doing your ajax request? I use that all the time

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to take input using ajax then this will help.

```
 public function index(Request $request)
   {
    if ($request->input('parameter')) {
      return response()->json(['result' => true]);
    }

  return view('dashboard');
 }
```

Comment: you didn't get my question i want to verify if it is simple POST request or AJAX request.